# Conditional Means in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I currently face a data manipulation issue in **R** for which I have not found a solution here so far (although there are many seemingly similar problems, which, however, did not lead me on the right path yet).

**Description of the Sample Data:**
The numbers (1-3) refer to separate entities that a respondent is questioned about. These entities have different roles (x) and attributes (y).

```
ID x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3
A  1  1  5  4  3  2
B  2  2  2  3  4  5
```

The important point here is that x1 is linked to y1, x2 to y2, etc.

**Goal:**
For each case. I want to have a mean score for y for each role x (in separate, additional columns, e.g., m1, m2, m3, m4, m5)

**Example:**

- For ID==A we would expect for x==1: (4+3)/2 = 3.5 ["2" is not needed as the "linked" value of x3 is not equal to 1]
- For ID==A we would expect for x==3: (2)/1 = 2
- For ID==B we would expect for x==1: NA
- For ID==B we would expect for x==2: (3+4+5)/3=4

Any hints? Thank you!

Comment: This may be just me being dense, but could you perhaps elaborate on your algorithm how to attain these conditional means?

Comment: Did you intend for the data point at A:x3 to be 3 instead of 5, based on "For ID==A we would expect for x==3: (2)/1 = 2"?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik  Thank you, please see the edited post.

Comment: @CJYetman: interesting, I have changed this quite some time ago (but you are right concerning the original version)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would restructure your data first, but given how it is, this might work...

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = '
ID x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3
A  1  1  3  4  3  2
B  2  2  2  3  4  5
')

for (entity in 1:3) {
  df[paste0('m', entity)] <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(row) { 
    value <- mean(df[row, 5:7][df[row, 2:4] == entity])
    ifelse(is.nan(value), NA, value)
  })
}

df
```

gives this...

```
  ID x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3  m1 m2 m3
1  A  1  1  3  4  3  2 3.5 NA  2
2  B  2  2  2  3  4  5  NA  4 NA
```

Comment: that looks pretty promising. I have to desect it later for study, but it certainly does what it should do. Thank you!